# Storyboard options not visible to iPad in Xcode v7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, ios-universal-app

Created a new project in `Xcode 7`. With default settings, it created a single storyboard with `use size classes` selected. I disabled `use size classes` option in storyboard because my project still needs to support `iOS 7.0`

I created a separate storyboard for iPad and tried to connect that in project settings. **But, can't see options for selecting iPad storyboard**.

Here it is a screenshot of settings in my project.

[image]

In above screenshot, it shows that I selected device as 'Universal'. Still I can select only one storyboard. For iPad, I don't have an option to select separate storyboard.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new storyboard file named "iPad", and then set as below in `Info.plist`. Don't forget to check `Is Initial View Controller` in iPad stroyborad.

[image]

Comment: I did that way already and it worked. Thank you for posting that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can only provide one interface here. Since you don't want to you size classes, you can manually set the initialViewController of iPad and iPhone storyboards in app delegate.
You need to remove main-interface all together from deployment screen.

```
    window.rootViewController = initialViewController()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and get initialViewController here

```
    private func initialViewController() -> UIViewController {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main-iPad", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
        } else {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main-iPhone", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can follow [this method](https://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/) too.

Comment: I don't think like this. There could be an another way to fix the project settings.

Comment: You can name your iPad storyboard Main~iPad.storyboard and let Main.storyboard be the Main controller defined in Deployment Info.